# Filtering values from inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I had a solution where the filtering of item tags worked. Updated so the books could receive multiple tags and added the tag array:

```
const bookListBefore = [
  { id: 1, tag: 'Fysik' },
  { id: 2, tag: 'Marketing' },
  { id: 3, tag: '' },
  ];

 const bookListNow = [
 { id: 1, tag: ['Fysik', 'Matematik'] },
 { id: 2, tag: ['Analytics', 'Marketing', 'Data'] },
 { id: 3, tag: [''] },
 ];
```

Now I am struggling on finding a solution to filter those items that have a specific tag. Before with the single tags I could perform a filter and could display items with specific tags with this solution:

```
const filteredList = bookList
    .filter(item => (item.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTextHome)
      || item.author.toLowerCase().includes(searchTextHome))
      && (selectedTags.length > 0 ? selectedTags.includes(item.tag) : true));

 <section className={stylesSCSS.bookContainer}>
        {filteredList.length === 0 ? emptyPlaceholder()
          : filteredList.map(item => (
            <BookItem
              cover={item.cover}
              item={item}
              userTagData={userTagData}
              onTagSelected={onTagSelected}
            />
          ))
        }
  </section>
```

The first part of the "search" filtering the bookList is about an input search field but this second part `(selectedTags.length > 0 ? selectedTags.includes(item.tag) : true)` Is where I am not able to filter the tag array, and have no ideas on how to use maybe spread operator or array functions to filter the tag arrays. Any ideas?

Comment: can you show how `selectedTags` looks like ? is it an array or string ?

Comment: selectedTags is an array of strings. @Code Maniac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will work with the array function `some`

```
selectedTags.length > 0 ? selectedTags.some(st => item.tag.includes(st)) : true
```

With this at least one selected tag should match the list of book tags and it will be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing an array to `includes`. `includes` takes two arguments the first one is a value to check and the second is the position in the array (optional)

```
[1,2,3].includes(1) //true
[1,2,3].includes(1,3) //false
```

You need to check each element from `tag` at a time

```
const { tag } = book

for(let item of tag){
    if(list.includes(item)) return true
}
return false
```

Your code should look like this

```
const filteredList = bookList.filter(item => 
    (item.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTextHome)
    || item.author.toLowerCase().includes(searchTextHome))

const result = selectedTags.length > 0 ? filteredList.filter(x =>{
    const { tag } = x

    for(let item of tag) {
        if(selectedTags.includes(item)) return true
    }
    return false
}) : filteredList
```

Comment: Thank you for showing how it works. Some interesting things in your solution @Dupocas